# Dropdown e Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocompletar

Tenho uma dúvida sobre como realizar uma determinada função.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que, quando fosse selecionado um determinado supervisor,
na caixa "técnico" aparece-se uma lista dos técnicos relacionados a ele.

Exemplo: selecionei o 3º supervisor, como mostra a imagem.
Na  caixa "técnico" deverá aparecer apenas os técnicos relacionados a ele.
Caso eu seleciona-se, por exemplo, outro supervisor. Apareceria apenas os técnicos relacionados a ele.

E assim por diante.

Não sei se ficou confuso. Alguém conseguiria me dar uma luz?

Comment: Vc tá usando algum plugin? De onde vêm a lista de técnicos ao selecionar um supervisor?

Comment: Acho que já entendi. A lista de técnicos são todos os técnicos, o que vc quer fazer é um filtro.... blz... mas, o que relaciona um supervisor a determinados técnicos?

Comment: Na realidade ainda não fiz isso. Estava pensando em resolver tudo com o javascript. Tem como?

Comment: Vc tem que fazer algum relacionamento de um supervisor com uma coleção de técnicos, para que o JS pode filtrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar jQuery para fazer esse filtro, mas é preciso relacionar o `select` "Supervisores" com o `select` "Técnicos". Para isso você pode criar um atributo `data-sup` nas `option` do `select` dos "Técnicos" colocando o código do supervisor relacionado. Veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $("#supervisor").change(function(){

      $("#tecnicos option")
      .hide(); // Escondo todos os options
      
      $("#tecnicos")
      .find("option[data-sup='"+$(this).val()+"']")
      .show() // mostro apenas os options relacionados ao valor do Supervisor escolhido
      .first() 
      .prop("selected", true);
   }).trigger("change");
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="supervisor">
   <option value="1">Super 1</option>
   <option value="2">Super 2</option>
   <option value="3">Super 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="tecnicos">
   <option data-sup="2" value="100">Téc 1</option>
   <option data-sup="2" value="200">Téc 2</option>
   <option data-sup="1" value="300">Téc 3</option>
   <option data-sup="1" value="400">Téc 4</option>
   <option data-sup="3" value="500">Téc 5</option>
   <option data-sup="3" value="600">Téc 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o evento [`onchange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) para executar uma função que filtra a lista de técnicos de acordo com o supervisor selecionado.

O evento `onchange()` chama a função `alterado()` passando `this` que é o próprio `select` dos supervisores. Dentro da função é só pegar a propriedade `value` e comparar para pegar a lista certa.

Abaixo um exemplo básico:

```js
var supervisorList = ['Super1', 'Super2'];

var tecnicoList1 = ['Tecnico1', 'Tecnico11'];
var tecnicoList2 = ['Tecnico2', 'Tecnico22'];

var supervisorSelect = document.getElementById("supervisor");
var tecnicoSelect = document.getElementById("tecnico");

inicializa();

function inicializa() {
  for (i = 0; i < supervisorList.length; i++) {
    var c = document.createElement("option");
    c.text = supervisorList[i];
    supervisorSelect.options.add(c, 1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < tecnicoList1.length; i++) {
    var c = document.createElement("option");
    c.text = tecnicoList1[i];
    tecnicoSelect.options.add(c, 1);
  }
}

function alterado(selectElement) {
  var val = selectElement.value;
  console.log(val);

  if (val) {
    limpaTecnicos();
    if (val == 'Super1') {
      for (i = 0; i < tecnicoList1.length; i++) {
        var c = document.createElement("option");
        c.text = tecnicoList1[i];
        tecnicoSelect.options.add(c, 1);
      }
    }
    if (val == 'Super2') {
      for (i = 0; i < tecnicoList2.length; i++) {
        var c = document.createElement("option");
        c.text = tecnicoList2[i];
        tecnicoSelect.options.add(c, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}

function limpaTecnicos() {

  for (i = tecnicoSelect.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tecnicoSelect.options.remove(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Supervisor:
  <select id="supervisor" onchange="alterado(this)">
</select>
</p>

<p>
  Técnico
  <select id="tecnico"></select>
</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado Felipe!  Vou tentar aplicar sem copiar pra entender melhor a lógica.. Valeu o/